# Как реализовать мультибота при помощи aiogram webhook?

Tags: python, aiogram, fastapi

```
urltulell = 'https://112c-176-48-4-18.eu.ngrok.io'
from fastapi import FastAPI
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher, Bot

import uvicorn


app = FastAPI()


WEBHOOK_PATH = f"/bot/63179018"
WEBHOOK_PATH2 = f"/bot/5874084"
WEBHOOK_URL1 = f"{urltulell}{WEBHOOK_PATH2}"
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{urltulell}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

bot = Bot(token='63179018')
bot2 = Bot(token='5874084')

dp = Dispatcher(bot,bot2)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    webhook_info = await bot.get_webhook_info() #1 бот
    print(webhook_info)
    if webhook_info.url != WEBHOOK_URL:
        await bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL) 
    webhook_info1 = await bot2.get_webhook_info() #2 бот
    print(webhook_info1)
    if webhook_info1.url != WEBHOOK_URL1:
        await bot2.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL1)





 @app.post(WEBHOOK_PATH) #1 бот
 async def bot_webhook(update: dict):
     telegram_update = types.Update(**update)
     Dispatcher.set_current(dp)
     Bot.set_current(botq)
     await dp.process_update(telegram_update)


@app.post(WEBHOOK_PATH2) #2 бот
async def bot_webhook(update: dict):
    telegram_update = types.Update(**update)
    Dispatcher.set_current(dp)
    Bot.set_current(bot2)
    await dp.process_update(telegram_update)


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def on_shutdown():
    await bot.session.close() #1
    await bot2.session.close() #2

if __name__=="__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=8000)
```

Тут я запускаю 2 ботов отдельно прописывая URL,PATH, @app.post и др.
как мне реализовать например цикл который будет по токенам из бд создавать @app.post и тд.(- не прописывать в коде отдельно каждого бота)

Comment: пробовал циклом for пробегатся по токенам но, то 1 бот работает нормально, а 2 отвечает в 1 бота